# React .map doesn't work while trying to set data for displaying on the chart

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, map-function

I want to display data from API on the chart and I know how to do it but I have error while using `.map` function. I want to separate `prices[0]`from `prices [1]` to have access to two of them because my response looks like this:

```json
"prices": [
    [
      1689598842536,
      30208.47
    ],
    [
      1689602431443,
      30274.72
    ],
```

Here is the code with .map function:

```js
 const params = useParams()
    const [coin, setCoin] = useState({})
    const [chart, setChart] = useState({})
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    const chartUrl = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${params.coinId}/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=30&precision=2`

    const url = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${params.coinId}`

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            setCoin(res.data)
            setLoading(true)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })

        axios.get(chartUrl).then((res) => {
            setChart(res)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }, [])

    const coinChartData = chart.prices.map(value => ({x: value[0], y: value[1]}))
```

I have got error in last line:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

I tried put `coinChartData` inside `useEffect` and it worked but I couldn't use `coinChartData` outside `useEffect` function.

Answer (score 2):

The initial value for `chart` is an empty object:

```
const [chart, setChart] = useState({})
```

That object has no `prices` property so, just as the error states, `chart.prices` is `undefined`.

You could perhaps initialize such a property to an empty array:

```
const [chart, setChart] = useState({ prices: [] })
```

Or you could use optional chaining when accessing a potentially `undefined` property:

```
const coinChartData = chart.prices?.map(value => ({x: value[0], y: value[1]}))
```

You may have other options as well, depending on where/how you eventually use this data.  But any way you look at it, if the object might not have the `prices` property then you can't always use that property.  You'd need to either ensure the property always exists or in some way conditionally check if it exists before trying to use it.